# How to setup oracle pl/sql server on local machine?

Tags: web-server

Ok, so i have Oracle 10g XE running on my windows machine. It has stored pl/sql procedures which generate HTML pages. So I have my DAD configured to listen to localhost at port 80. So i can access those pages. What i need to know is how to open this pages to public. I found a ton of manuals on how to do it with apache server, but how do i do it with the HTTP server that comes with Oracle XE?

Answer (score 2):

I would **STRONGLY** advise against opening up the Oracle XE web server "to the public".  Take the time to write an application layer with SQL injection checks and the like, and keep access to your Oracle server limited to a small list of authorized hosts that you know and trust.
Opening up the Oracle XE web server to the public means anyone stumbling around on the internet will have access to anything running on that web server, which includes some administrative functions that you probably don't want them to have access to.

---

Having said all that, the magic invocation `exec dbms_xdb.setListenerLocalAccess(false);` (as the `sys` user) should remove the "local-access-only" restriction.